# Why is there a resistor and capacitor between SW and VOUT on a TPS61322 5 V switching regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost

The TPS61322 datasheet shows a typical circuit like this:

[image: typical TPS61322 circuit]

However, it later shows a "layout example" that differs slightly:

[image: layout example of the tps61322]

The second picture shows a resistor and capacitor between SW and VOUT pins. I don't know the purpose of these components nor how to go about determining the values of them. The circuit works fine without them.

Why is there a resistor and capacitor between SW and VOUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They form a [snubber circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber):

> A snubber circuit consisting of a resistor R1 and a capacitor C2 is needed if the
> Schottky diode D1 is soldered. The capacitance of C2 must be larger than triple times of the diode capacitance.
> The typical value of the resistor R1 is 5 Ω, and the typical value of the capacitor C2 is 120 pF.
>
> [TPS61322 datasheet p. 17](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61322.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I don't know how I missed this.

Comment: @SoberTillNoon Happy to help. It's much easier when you know what to look for -- I knew it was a snubber so I just hit Ctrl+F "snub" and found the quoted text. Thanks for accepting the answer!